# saving datetimefiled in django models, int() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

This is my django model

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):

    email = models.ForeignKey(EmailAddress)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I'm tying to create an model instance and tring to save it like This

x = Mymodel(email_object,timezone.now())

x.save()

then its giving this error

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'`

Instead of timezone.now() I stored time as string ,then its giving this error

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2014-11-29 06:00:00.000000 08:00'`

How can I fix this .. please help me.. in which format I have to send the datetime object

Comment: i tried it same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

There is also `auto_now` for an 'updated on' field.

Comment: I should not change the model, I have to create an instance and save it.

Comment: Since the created field already has a default value with the current time, I think you can get away with just passing the e-mail: `x=Mymodel.objects.create(email_object)`. This also does the save thing so no need to call save() anymore.

Comment: Thak you.. what you said is correct , and fixed my problem.

Comment: If you change the answer with ur comment , I'll accept the answer .

Comment: You could mark the answer as correct so others can use it too.